# Sorting First array and arranging second array elements as per new position of first

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Problem is  i have 2 arrays `int input2[]={5,1,9,3,8};` and `int input3[]={2,0,3,6,1};`
 have sorted array input2 using  `Arrays.sort(input2);` now i want to place elements in array  `inputs3` as per the new positions of elements of array `input2`

input array pre Sort- 5,1,9,3,8
input array post Sort - 1,3,5,8,9
now the elements of array input3 should also change as per the positions of array input2
preSort 2,0,3,6,1
Post sort 0,6,2,1,3

though i have written the code , but looking for an optimal solution`enter code here`

```
private static int[] swap(int[] arr, int i, int j,int [] arr2) {
    arr2[i]=arr[j];
    return arr2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input2[]={5,1,9,3,8};
    int input3[]={2,0,3,6,1};
    int []temp=input2.clone();
    int []input4=input3.clone();
    Arrays.sort(input2);

    for(int i=0;i<=input2.length-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=input2.length;j++){
            if(input2[i]==temp[j]){
                input4= swap(input3,i,j,input4);
                break;
            }  
        } 
    }        
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't use a Map instead of two arrays?

Comment: What happens if one array has duplicate elements?

Comment: Don't do that. Create a class that holds the two integers and is comparable on the first. Create an array of that class. Sort it, and you'll have the second integers sorted as well.

Comment: Maybe use a Map<Integer, Integer>. Get the keys (first array), sort the keys, then get the value (second array) from the key?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably these values (`input2`, `input3`) bear some relationship to one another? Like, they are the x, y coordinates of some points, or something like that? If so, you should put them together into some objects, and then sort the objects.

```
public class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}

public void sortPoints() {
    int xs[] = { 5, 1, 9, 3, 8 };
    int ys[] = { 2, 0, 3, 6, 1 };
    List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < xs.length; ++i) {
        points.add(new Point(xs[i], ys[i]));
    }

    Collections.sort(points, (a, b) -> a.getX() - b.getX());

    points.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getY())); 
}
```

Comment: Reason for not using Map is to find a way using Array only, that is requirement  of this question

Comment: @GSK Was this comment intended for Sazzad's answer? My solution does not use a `Map`.

Comment: for @ TangledUpInBlue

Answer (score 1):

Beside other solutions of making a class, an alternative solution looks like,

```
public class SortTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        TreeMap sortedMap = new TreeMap();

        map.put(5, 2);
        map.put(1, 0);
        map.put(9, 3);
        map.put(3, 6);
        map.put(8, 1);

        sortedMap.putAll(map);
        System.out.println("results: " + sortedMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your swap method to switch the elements of all lists you want to swap at the same time at once.

```
private static int[] swap(int i, int j,List<int[]>  listOfArrays) {
       for(int[] array : listOfArrays) {
           int tmp = array[i];
           array[i]=array[j];
           array[j]=tmp;
       }
       return arr2;
}
```

But you will have to write your own sort.

The other option is to use functional Interfaces and swap the 3rd array at comparison. with the

```
Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

method.

In other words, after sorting it's already to late, you have to do it while sorting. Or the initial array needs to be reconstructable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Java 8, you can generate an array of Integer indices (using Integer because lambda compare doesn't work with primitives), sort the array of indices according to input2, then reorder input2 and input3 in place according to the array of indices.

```
package x;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input2[]={5,1,9,3,8}; 
        int input3[]={2,0,3,6,1};
        // generate array of indices
        Integer[] I = new Integer [input2.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < I.length; i++)
            I[i] = i;
        // sort array of indices according to input2
        Arrays.sort(I, (i, j) -> input2[i]-input2[j]);
        // reorder input2 and input3 in place using sorted indices
        // also reorder indices back to 0 to length-1
        // time complexity is O(n)
        for(int i = 0; i < I.length; i++){
            if(i != I[i]){
                int t2 = input2[i];
                int t3 = input3[i];
                int j;
                int k = i;
                while(i != (j = I[k])){
                    input2[k] = input2[j];
                    input3[k] = input3[j];
                    I[k] = k;
                    k = j;
                }
                input2[k] = t2;
                input3[k] = t3;
                I[k] = k;
            }
        }
        // display result
        for (int i = 0; i < input2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("input2 " + input2[i] + " input3 " + input3[i]);
        }
    }
}
```